# date format convertion in logstash elk stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have a date column in my table that I fetch using jdbc input in logstash. The problem is logstash gives a wrong value to elasticsearch stack.

For example if I have a date `start_date="2018-03-01"` in elasticsearch I would get the value `"2018-02-28 23:00:00.000"`.

What I want is to keep the format of start_date or at least output the value "`2018-03-01 00:00:00.000`" to elasticsearch. 
I tried to use this filter :

```
date {
    timezone => "UTC"
    match => ["start_date" , "ISO8601", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Is it possible that you are losing time because of UTC conversion? What is the timezone of the input date?

Comment: the input date is made using jdbc from  a table.so there's no timezone in the input date because it's just in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'.The server where logstash is installed is in "CET" timezone,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, you are trying to convert it to UTC timezone. You need to change your configuration like this:

```
date {
  match => ["start_date" , "yyyy-MM-dd"]
}
```

This would be enough to parse your date.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: it didn't work, it  gave me "tags:_dateparsefailure" and still without the utc timezone i have date minus one houre in kibana filter of data parsed from database

Comment: It is because you are looking at old timestamp value, since date is parsed your event will move to start_date timestamp